# "Configure: Error: Could Not Find a Working Compiler, See config.log For Details"

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, gmp, msys

I have to handle very long numbers in C++. I saw online that the easiest way to do it is install the GMP library, but I have a problem.
When i execute the msys.bat file inside the compiler folder and when i execute the command `./configure --prefix=/d/Libraries_For_C_and_C++/GMP --enable-cxx` it gives me an error

> configure: error: could not find a working compiler,  see config.log for details

I have tried to install the compiler several times but the error message is the same.

The config.log file is:

```
> This file contains any messages produced by compilers while running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.
> 
> It was created by GNU MP configure 6.1.2, which was generated by GNU
> Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was
> 
>   $ ./configure --prefix=/d/Libraries_For_C_and_C++/GMP --enable-cxx
> 
> ## --------- ##
> ## Platform. ##
> ## --------- ##
> 
> hostname = DESKTOP-N92E9KJ uname -m = i686 uname -r = 1.0.19(0.48/3/2)
> uname -s = MINGW32_NT-6.2 uname -v = 2016-07-13 17:45
> 
> /usr/bin/uname -p = unknown /bin/uname -X     = unknown
> 
> /bin/arch              = unknown /usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
> /usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown /usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
> /bin/machine           = unknown /usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
> /bin/universe          = unknown
> 
> PATH: . PATH: /usr/local/bin PATH: /mingw/bin PATH: /bin PATH:
> /c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath PATH:
> /c/Windows/system32 PATH: /c/Windows PATH: /c/Windows/System32/Wbem
> PATH: /c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/ PATH:
> /c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA
> Corporation/PhysX/Common PATH: /c/Users/Novati
> Giovanni/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps PATH: .
> 
> 
> ## ----------- ##
> ## Core tests. ##
> ## ----------- ##
> 
> configure:3055: checking build system type configure:3069: result:
> i686-pc-mingw32 configure:3089: checking host system type
> configure:3102: result: i686-pc-mingw32 configure:3139: checking for a
> BSD-compatible install configure:3207: result: /bin/install -c
> configure:3218: checking whether build environment is sane
> configure:3273: result: yes configure:3424: checking for a thread-safe
> mkdir -p configure:3463: result: /bin/mkdir -p configure:3470:
> checking for gawk configure:3486: found /bin/gawk configure:3497:
> result: gawk configure:3508: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
> configure:3530: result: yes configure:3559: checking whether make
> supports nested variables configure:3576: result: yes configure:3705:
> checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
> configure:3714: result: no User: ABI= CC= CFLAGS=(unset)
> CPPFLAGS=(unset) MPN_PATH= GMP: abilist=32 cclist=gcc icc cc
> configure:5801: gcc 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null configure:5804: $? = 1
> configure:5858: checking compiler gcc -m32 -O2 -pedantic
> -fomit-frame-pointer  Test compile:  configure:5872: gcc -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer  conftest.c >&5 ./configure: line 5873: gcc: command not found configure:5875: $? = 127 failed program was:
> 
> int main () { return 0; } configure:6962: result: no configure:5858:
> checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer  Test
> compile:  configure:5872: gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer 
> conftest.c >&5 ./configure: line 5873: gcc: command not found
> configure:5875: $? = 127 failed program was:
> 
> int main () { return 0; } configure:6962: result: no configure:5779:
> icc -c conftest.c >&5 ./configure: line 5780: icc: command not found
> configure:5782: $? = 127 configure:5801: icc 2>&1 | grep xlc
> >/dev/null configure:5804: $? = 1 configure:5858: checking compiler icc -no-gcc  Test compile:  configure:5872: icc -no-gcc  conftest.c
> >&5 ./configure: line 5873: icc: command not found configure:5875: $? = 127 failed program was:
> 
> int main () { return 0; } configure:6962: result: no configure:5779:
> cc -c conftest.c >&5 ./configure: line 5780: cc: command not found
> configure:5782: $? = 127 configure:5801: cc 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null
> configure:5804: $? = 1 configure:5858: checking compiler cc -O  Test
> compile:  configure:5872: cc -O  conftest.c >&5 ./configure: line
> 5873: cc: command not found configure:5875: $? = 127 failed program
> was:
> 
> int main () { return 0; } configure:6962: result: no configure:7200:
> error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details
> 
> ## ---------------- ##
> ## Cache variables. ##
> ## ---------------- ##
> 
> ac_cv_build=i686-pc-mingw32 ac_cv_env_ABI_set= ac_cv_env_ABI_value=
> ac_cv_env_CCC_set= ac_cv_env_CCC_value= ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_BUILD_set=
> ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_BUILD_value= ac_cv_env_CC_set= ac_cv_env_CC_value=
> ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set= ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value= ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
> ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value= ac_cv_env_CPP_FOR_BUILD_set=
> ac_cv_env_CPP_FOR_BUILD_value= ac_cv_env_CPP_set= ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
> ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set= ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value= ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
> ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value= ac_cv_env_CXX_set= ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
> ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set= ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value= ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
> ac_cv_env_LIBS_value= ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
> ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value= ac_cv_env_M4_set=
> ac_cv_env_M4_value= ac_cv_env_YACC_set= ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
> ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set= ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
> ac_cv_env_build_alias_set= ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
> ac_cv_env_host_alias_set= ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
> ac_cv_env_target_alias_set= ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
> ac_cv_host=i686-pc-mingw32 ac_cv_path_install='/bin/install -c'
> ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
> ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes
> 
> ## ----------------- ##
> ## Output variables. ##
> ## ----------------- ##
> 
> ABI='' ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /d/Libraries_For_C_and_C++/gmp-6.1.2/missing
> aclocal-1.15' AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}' AM_BACKSLASH='\'
> AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)' AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
> AM_V='$(V)' AR='' AS='' ASMFLAGS='' AUTOCONF='${SHELL}
> /d/Libraries_For_C_and_C++/gmp-6.1.2/missing autoconf'
> AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /d/Libraries_For_C_and_C++/gmp-6.1.2/missing
> autoheader' AUTOMAKE='${SHELL}
> /d/Libraries_For_C_and_C++/gmp-6.1.2/missing automake-1.15' AWK='gawk'
> CALLING_CONVENTIONS_OBJS='x86call.lo x86check$U.lo' CC='' CCAS=''
> CC_FOR_BUILD='' CFLAGS='' CPP='' CPPFLAGS='' CPP_FOR_BUILD='' CXX=''
> CXXCPP='' CXXFLAGS='' CYGPATH_W='echo' DEFN_LONG_LONG_LIMB='' DEFS=''
> DLLTOOL='' DSYMUTIL='' DUMPBIN='' ECHO_C='' ECHO_N='-n' ECHO_T=''
> EGREP='' ENABLE_STATIC_FALSE='' ENABLE_STATIC_TRUE='' EXEEXT=''
> EXEEXT_FOR_BUILD='' FGREP='' GMP_LDFLAGS='' GMP_LIMB_BITS=''
> GMP_NAIL_BITS='0' GREP='' HAVE_CLOCK_01='' HAVE_CPUTIME_01=''
> HAVE_GETRUSAGE_01='' HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY_01=''
> HAVE_HOST_CPU_FAMILY_power='0' HAVE_HOST_CPU_FAMILY_powerpc='0'
> HAVE_SIGACTION_01='' HAVE_SIGALTSTACK_01='' HAVE_SIGSTACK_01=''
> HAVE_STACK_T_01='' HAVE_SYS_RESOURCE_H_01='' INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL}
> -m 644' INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}' INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}' INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s' LD='' LDFLAGS='' LEX=''
> LEXLIB='' LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT='' LIBCURSES='' LIBGMPXX_LDFLAGS=''
> LIBGMP_DLL='' LIBGMP_LDFLAGS='' LIBM='' LIBM_FOR_BUILD='' LIBOBJS=''
> LIBREADLINE='' LIBS='' LIBTOOL='' LIPO='' LN_S='' LTLIBOBJS=''
> LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH='' M4='' MAINT='#' MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
> MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#' MAKEINFO='${SHELL}
> /d/Libraries_For_C_and_C++/gmp-6.1.2/missing makeinfo'
> MANIFEST_TOOL='' MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p' NM='' NMEDIT='' OBJDUMP=''
> OBJEXT='' OTOOL64='' OTOOL='' PACKAGE='gmp'
> PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='gmp-bugs@gmplib.org, see
> https://gmplib.org/manual/Reporting-Bugs.html' PACKAGE_NAME='GNU MP'
> PACKAGE_STRING='GNU MP 6.1.2' PACKAGE_TARNAME='gmp'
> PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/gmp/' PACKAGE_VERSION='6.1.2'
> PATH_SEPARATOR=':' RANLIB='' SED='' SET_MAKE='' SHELL='/bin/sh'
> SPEED_CYCLECOUNTER_OBJ='pentium.lo' STRIP='' TAL_OBJECT=''
> TUNE_LIBS='' TUNE_SQR_OBJ='' U_FOR_BUILD='' VERSION='6.1.2'
> WANT_CXX_FALSE='' WANT_CXX_TRUE='' WITH_READLINE_01='' YACC=''
> YFLAGS='' ac_ct_AR='' ac_ct_CC='' ac_ct_CXX='' ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
> am__EXEEXT_FALSE='' am__EXEEXT_TRUE='' am__isrc='' am__leading_dot='.'
> am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"' am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
> bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin' build='i686-pc-mingw32' build_alias=''
> build_cpu='i686' build_os='mingw32' build_vendor='pc'
> datadir='${datarootdir}' datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
> docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}' dvidir='${docdir}'
> exec_prefix='NONE' gmp_srclinks='' host='i686-pc-mingw32'
> host_alias='' host_cpu='i686' host_os='mingw32' host_vendor='pc'
> htmldir='${docdir}' includedir='${prefix}/include'
> infodir='${datarootdir}/info' install_sh='${SHELL}
> /d/Libraries_For_C_and_C++/gmp-6.1.2/install-sh'
> libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib' libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
> localedir='${datarootdir}/locale' localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
> mandir='${datarootdir}/man' mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)' mpn_objects=''
> mpn_objs_in_libgmp='' oldincludedir='/usr/include' pdfdir='${docdir}'
> prefix='/d/Libraries_For_C_and_C++/GMP'
> program_transform_name='s,x,x,' psdir='${docdir}'
> sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin' sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
> sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc' target_alias=''
> 
> ## ----------- ##
> ## confdefs.h. ##
> ## ----------- ##
> 
> /* confdefs.h */
> #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU MP"
> #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gmp"
> #define PACKAGE_VERSION "6.1.2"
> #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU MP 6.1.2"
> #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "gmp-bugs@gmplib.org, see https://gmplib.org/manual/Reporting-Bugs.html"
> #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/gmp/"
> #define PACKAGE "gmp"
> #define VERSION "6.1.2"
> #define WANT_FFT 1
> #define HAVE_HOST_CPU_i686 1
> 
> configure: exit 1
```

What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: You would get better and faster help if you included a more detailed description of what you did, and what exactly went wrong. It takes people a long time to write a step-by-step guide in the answer box. But an expert can look at what you did, and the failure mode, and quickly tell you where you went wrong. Use the [edit] link to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the error by updating the MinGW compilator.
I also found this guide if someone need it:

> https://hyperactve.blogspot.com/2012/04/gmp-c-library-in-windows-mingwmsys.html